Time Complexity of Backtracking solution - Leetcode 473. Matchsticks to Square
The following is a Leetcode problem: 473. Matchsticks to Square (https://leetcode.com/problems/matchsticks-to-square/description/)

Problem Statement
You have an array, matchsticks, of size n, with different matchstick lengths. You want to create a square using all the matchsticks, without breaking them. If you can, return true. If you can't, return false.
Example 1:

Input: matchsticks = [1,1,2,2,2]

Output: true

Explanation: You can form a square with length 2, one side of the square came two sticks with length 1.


Example 2:

Input: matchsticks = [3,3,3,3,4]

Output: false

Explanation: You cannot find a way to form a square with all the matchsticks.


Constraints:

1 <= n <= 15

1 <= matchsticks[i] <= 10^8



I have seen O(4^n) and O(n*2^n) solutions to this problem. I have solved the problem differently through a solution that I haven't seen anywhere else, and I am not sure what its time complexity is. I will explain the solution with the example matchsticks = [4, 4, 4, 3, 1] -> sideLength = 4. I solved it in C++. The code is at the end:
My solution: For each side, iterate through the matchsticks array, and for each matchstick explore both decisions: add it to the current side, and not add it to the current side. Once a side is complete, move on to the next side, starting the iteration over the matchsticks array from the beginning (i=0). Since there are two decisions per element, I was initially tempted to say that the time complexity is O(2^n). The height of the entire tree is not really n, but the height of individual subtrees is, at most. I am a bit confused here. How does one go about determining the time complexity of such a backtracking solution?

Code:
class Solution {
public:
    bool makesquare(const std::vector<int>& matchsticks) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int m : matchsticks)
            sum += m;

        if(sum % 4 != 0)
            return false;

        int sideLength = sum / 4;
        std::vector<bool> available(matchsticks.size(), true);
        return dfs(matchsticks, sideLength, 0, 0, available, 4);
    }

    bool dfs(const std::vector<int>& matchsticks, int sideLength, int currSideLength, int i, std::vector<bool>& available, int numRemainingSides) {
        if(currSideLength == sideLength) {
            currSideLength = 0;
            numRemainingSides --;
            i = 0;  // restart choice of matches
            if(numRemainingSides == 0)
                return true;
        }
        if(i == matchsticks.size())
            return false;

        if(available[i]) {
            // take current matchstick for the current side
            available[i] = false;
            if(dfs(matchsticks, sideLength, currSideLength + matchsticks[i], i+1, available, numRemainingSides))
                return true;
            // do not take the current matchstick for the current side
            available[i] = true;
        }
        if(dfs(matchsticks, sideLength, currSideLength, i+1, available, numRemainingSides))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};


The worst case is 2^n or worse since, when there is no subset of sticks whose total length equals the required side length, the algorithm explores all 2^n subsets for the first side.

Time Complexity of Backtracking solution to Leetcode 473. Matchsticks to Square

"Since there are two decisions per element" It is not clear where you take this from. There is a four-prong decision for each element: you add it to the first side, to the second side, to the third side, or to the fourth side. So the complexity seems to be O(4^n).

@n.m.couldbeanAI , your comment is correct for the following solution: "Each matchstick has to go on one of the 4 sides. Hence, we try all configurations. Since for each matchstick we try placing it on all 4 sides and backtracking when we fail to create a square, we have a decision tree with 4 branches per matchstick -> time complexity: O(4^n).". In this question I ask about another way of solving the problem, which uses a binary decision tree instead.

@user12002570 , you're right in pointing out that other question. I had initially created that other question where I detailed the solutions that I had seen online together with my solution which I hadn't seen anywhere else. For some reason my question was downvoted and closed, so I created this new question where I only focus on my solution.

But @EricPostpischil , every time you get the desired sideLength for a side you start a new subtree of max size 2^n, and this may happen multiple times if you go down the 'incorrect' branch and then have to backtrack, right? How does one go about finding the time complexity of the worst case?

@monre: I made no assertion about what happens when you get the desired length. Consider a set of matchsticks containing n sticks of length 1 for any n that is not a multiple of 4. The side length would have to be n/4, which is not an integer, so no subset of sticks would have that length. So the algorithm would search all 2^n subsets in vain, never getting the desired length. Thus, we know there is at least one case that takes 2^n time. That suffices to prove this algorithm inefficient. I do not think completing the analysis is very interesting.

How does one go about determining the time complexity of such a backtracking solution?  I usually "cheat" by incrementing a counter when I do the operation, and then plot the data size and its counter and see if the plot is constant, log n, n, n^2, n! or whatever.  Assuming a good set of data, to avoid skewing numbers such as from a lopsided tree.

@EricPostpischil , you are right in noting that if n/4 is not an integer no subset of sticks would have the desired length, and hence the algorithm would search all 2^n subsets in vain. However, I don't think this is the worst scenario, and hence neither the worst time complexity. What would be worse, is that for several of those branches the desired length is obtained for one or more sides, and every time this happens a new 2^n subtree is initiated. But then for some later side, the desired length is not obtained, having to backtrack and try other subtrees. Does that make sense?

I can produce an input of length 15 that will force your program to make >1,000,000 recursive calls. This doesn't quite look like a binary anything to me.

Self duplicate of Time Complexity of Backtracking solution to Leetcode 473. Matchsticks to Square

@n.m.couldbeanAI The fact that you have to stop if the first or second edges work out is a significant complication. I don't have a formal proof, but I believe that the answer is O(4^n / n). See my answer.

I mean first or second edges fail to work out, not work out. My answer has a heuristic for why that answer is reasonable, but not a proof. It does demonstrate, though, that you can't do better.

One more note. I've found that the addition of a language tag makes posts visible to a lot of people who automatically downvote anything that looks like complexity analysis.

@btilly Yes, the premature return false complicates the situation, but it doesn't magically uncomplicate it back down to O(n^2). O(n^4) was my rough estimate. I don't believe that that early return really matters (so the real worst case complexity is probably still O(n^4)) but I cannot come up with a counterexample just yet.

@btilly you're confusing computer science with programming. I wouldn't downvote this, as it appears to be a well thought-out question. But presenting working code and asking about some theoretical mathematical property of said code seems off-topic to me.

@miken32 Only poor programmers refuse to think about how computer science is part of their profession. You can recognize them when the code that they wrote failed to scale, and brought down production. I've had to fix a number of such bugs in my life.

@btilly I'm not suggesting it's not an important thing for programmers to know about, it's just not not on-topic at this particular web site, IMO.

@miken32: Asking about computational complexity at this level with code like this is on topic for Stack Overflow.

@btilly, I can only speak for my downvoting, and it's because of the repost. OP, please don't repost closed questions: "Do not post your question a second time, as it will be closed as a duplicate of your first question, and may attract downvotes. Also, do not delete your question and re-ask it, as your previous question will be undeleted and your new one closed as a duplicate.". Instead, edit to improve them and let the community decide whether they should be reopened.

This is a complicated algorithm to analyze because each time you see an element, you make a binary choice. But then you can see the same element potentially up to 3 times. Which gives a trivial upper bound of O(8^n). However if you think about it, you'll see that we've really divided up the question of making 4 possible choices over 3 passes. If we didn't evaluate after the first or second passes, but only at the end of the third, we'd wind up with 4^n combinations, which would take O(4^n) work.
The question therefore becomes, how much do we gain by not continuing on if we fail to make our first or second edges work out?
We can gain some intuition from the central limit theorem. Suppose that n is a multiple of 4. How many ways are there of taking a set of n things and dividing it into two piles of equal size? The answer is O(2^n / sqrt(n)). And then how many ways are there of dividing first pile again into two piles of equal size? The answer is O(2^(n/2) / sqrt(n)). So if we went by counts of edges rather than sizes, we'd expect there to be O(2^(3/2 n) / n) to do the first two passes that require us to do the O(2^(n/2)) work to do the third pass. Resulting in O(4^n / n) work.
I believe, but cannot prove that this is the worst case. However I can produce a family of adversarial inputs for which solving your problem looks very much like that simpler one, and demonstrate that you can't do better than that back of the envelope.
My example is the following family of adversarial inputs:
[3, 4, 4, 5, 14, 15, 17, 18]
[3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 30, 31, 33, 34]
[3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 46, 47, 49, 50]

And in general the kth will contain a 3, then 4 repeated 2k-2 times. And then 16k-2, 16k-1, 16k+1, 16k+2.
This sums to 80k. You will be attempting to make sides of length 20k. This can be done with the 3, the 16k+1, and any k-1 of the 4 elements. It can also be done with the 5, the 16k-1, and any k-1 of the 4 elements. It cannot be done in any other way because as soon as you add the 16k-2 or 16k+2 edges you wind up with something with a remainder of 2 when you divide by 4. There is no way to get rid of that remainder other than to put the other one in, but then you get a side of length 32k, which is too long.
n is, of course, 4k+4. Because we have 4k-2 4's, a 3, a 5, and then 4 large elements.
What happens when we put these adversarial inputs in to your algorithm?
The first pass takes O(2^n) as expected. (I will use k where I have to, and n whenever it is convenient.) We really don't hit 20k unless we've decided to include two of the final 4 elements.
Exactly 2 (4k-2 choose k-1) times, we finished the first pass perfectly, and try the second pass. Each time we do, we have 3/4 of the elements. And that takes O(2^(3/4 n)). For each one, the second pass succeeds (3k-1 choose k-1) times.
For each of those successful first then second passes, we do a third pass. Each third pass then takes O(2^(n/2)).
The giant question is how many of those choose's do we get. Because it is a large number, I'm going to switch to logarithms.
log((first pass #) * (second pass #))
  = log((4k-2 choose k-1) * (3k-1 choose k-1))
  = log((4k-2)! / (k-1)! / (3k-1)!)
    + log((3k-1)! / (k-1)! / (2k)!)
  = log((4k-2)!) - log((k-1)!) - log((3k-1)!)
    + log((3k-1)!) - log((k-1)!) - log((2k)!)
  = log((4k-2)!) - 2 log((k-1)!) - log((2k)!)

Now we can pull out Stirling's Approximation.
log(m!) = m log(m) - m + 1/2 log(2πm) + O(1/m)

And so
log((first pass #) * (second pass #))
  = log((4k-2)!) - 2 log((k-1)!) - log((2k)!)
  = (4k-2) log(4k-2) - (4k-2) + 1/2 log(2π (4k-2))
    - 2( (k-1) log(k-1) - (k-1) + 1/2 log(2π (k-1)) )
    - ( (2k) log(2k) - 2k + 1/2 log(2π (2k)) )
    + O(1/k)

Now let's let O(1) errors pass. So m log(m + O(1)) can be replaced with m log(m), (m + O(1)) can be replaced with m, and 1/2 log(O(1) m) can be replaced with 1/2 log(m)...
  = (4k-2) log(4k) - 4k + 1/2 log(k)
    - 2 ( (k-1) log(k) - k + 1/2 log(k) )
    - ( (2k) log(2k) - 2k + 1/2 log(k) )
    + O(1)
  = (4k-2) log(4k)  - 4k + 1/2 log(k)
    - (2k-2) log(k) + 2k - log(k)
    - (2k) log(2k)  + 2k - 1/2 log(k)
    + O(1)
  = (4k-2) (2 log(2) + log(k))
    - (2k-2) log(k)
    - (2k) (log(2) + log(k))
    - log(k) + O(1)
  = 8k log(2) + 4k log(k) - 2 log(k)
    - 2k log(k) + 2 log(k)
    - 2k log(2) - 2k log(k)
    - log(k) + O(1)

And now gather like terms. The k log(2) have 8 - 2 = 6. The k log(k) have 4 - 2 - 2 = 0. And the log(k) have -2 + 2 - 1 = -1. So we get
  = 6k log(2) - log(k) + O(1)
  = log(2^(6k) / k) + O(1)

So the number of combinations of first and second passes is (undoing the logs), O(2^(6k) / k). Remember that n = 4k + 4 and so O(2^(6k) / k) = O(2^(3/2 n) / n). Then for each of those we do another O(2^(n/2)) work on the third pass, resulting in a total of O(2^(2n) / n) = O(4^n / n) work.
I'll happily give rep for anyone who can fix my heuristic into a proof that the worst case can't be worse than that.

Mindblowing, thank you very much for the effort and detailed explanation @btilly . I had created a more "complete" question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79054379/time-complexity-of-backtracking-solution-to-leetcode-473-matchsticks-to-square) with another two solutions if you are also interested in taking a look - it was also downvoted and closed, hence why I created this simpler question. Thank you.

"you can't do better than that" --- this algorithm can't do better than that, but one that can handle a bunch of identical numbers more efficiently can deal with your inputs. You cannot prove that no algorithm can do better unless you have a proof that P≠NP, or something of that caliber, up your sleeve.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The question wasn't what the most efficient possible algorithm can do. It was what THIS algorithm can do. Yes, an algorithm that can handle identical numbers can handle this case, but I can still produce inputs that will be O(4^n / p(n)). A dynamic programming algorithm can be a pseudopolynomial times 2^n. And this problem is provably NP-complete.

If I'm not mistaken, handling duplicate entries can still be as bad as O(4^n / n^3). If m is the maximum value, the dynamic programming approach can be reduced to something like O(m * 2^n / n) - I'm too lazy to figure it out exactly.

It's just a clarification, not that  think you really think that  way.
